# Hashes (MD5, SHA1, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512) - why isn't it possible to get the value back from the hash?

Tags: c#, .net, security, hash, cryptography

[On this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/cumpsd/pages/81507.aspx), there is a sentence as below:

> *This hash is unique for the given text. If you use the hash function
>   on the same text again, you'll get the same hash. But there is no way
>   to get the given text from the hash.*

Forgive my ignorance on math but I cannot understand why it is not possible to get the given text from the hash.

I would understand if we use one key to encrypt the value and another to decrypt but I cannot figure it out in my mind. What is really going on here behind the scenes?

Anything that clears my mind will be appreciated.

Comment: Read the wikipedia articles on these hashing algorithms. Should help you understand. The entire point is for them to be unique. I should add you certainly can figure out what the text belongs to what has provided you have certain information. Its a brute force method, for example all known values for md5 are known. So given a particular array of characters one can figure out what the value was.  Just using these hashing alogorithms wouldn't be smart, you need to use a salt, otherwise even SHA512 given enough time is weak.

Comment: @Ramhound ok, now I am confused. Oded suggested below that they are not unique and you are saying they are.

Comment: A more correct explanation would read something like: "This hash function is highly unlikely to give the same output for different inputs, and hence can be considered unique."

Comment: @Ramhound - Hashes have collisions. Even with MD5 there are known inputs that produce the same hash.

Comment: @Oded - I know that. MD5 in particular because of the amount of bytes it calls for. You cannot hash more bytes then it supports with a collision. With that said a rainbow table is still possible for MD5.  I suppose there is a limit to that.  I regret even making that statement.

Comment: @Ramhound - True abut rainbow tables, but they tend to be limited to inputs of ASCII + digits. Adding some Unicode to the salt will make the hash mostly immune to rainbow tables (just having a salt may be enough).

Comment: Hashes hash bytes, not characters. "Adding some Unicode to the salt" is meaningless - the salt is a set number of bytes, not characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hashing is not encryption.

A hash produces a "digest" - a summary of the input. Whatever the input size, the hash size is always the same (see how MD5 returns the same size result for any input size).

With a hash, you can get the *same* hash from several different inputs (hash collisions) - how would you reverse this? Which is the *correct* input?

I suggest reading [this blog post from Troy Hunt](http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/06/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-7.html) on the matter in order to gain better understanding of hashes, passwords and security.

Encryption is a different thing - you would get a different cypher from the input and key - and the size of the cypher will tend to be larger as the input is larger. This is *reversible* if you have the right key.

---

Update (following the different comments):

Though collisions can happen, when using a cryptographically significant hash (like the ones you have posted about), they will be rare and difficult to produce.

When hashing passwords, *always* use a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) - this reduces the chances of the hash being reversed by [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) to almost nothing (assuming a good salt has been used).

You need to decide about the tradeoffs of the cost of hashing (can be processor intensive) and the cost of what you are protecting.

As you are simply protecting the login details, using the .NET membership provider should provide enough security.

Comment: Ok, this is something I haven't been aware of so far. Then storing plain text passwords as hash inside a database has no point given the fact that someone can actually log in with multiple different passwords latter.

Comment: @tugberk - I said collisions _can_ happen. It depends on the hash what the likelihood of that happening is. Finding a collision is not easy. But with MD5, if you don't use salting, there _are_ lookup tables of hashes that map back to inputs (lookup rainbow tables).

Comment: @tugberk: Yes, indeed. If a hashed password is stored in the DB, there are multiple valid passwords that map to this cache. However, if the hash function is a *cryptographically secure* hash function (and the ones you mentioned in your question are), then it's very hard to *find* a password that maps to a given hash.

Comment: thanks! Is there any chance of collision If salting is being used?

Comment: @tugberk - There is always a _chance_. That's not the point. I added [a link](http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/06/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-7.html) to a good article on this subject.

Comment: @tugberk - Yes, the chances remain the same.  I should make this statement clear.  The limits of said hashing remain.  2^256 bytes will remain.  The only thing that changes with a salt is the known collisions wll be different.

Comment: @Oded ok, it is more clear now. lastly, which one would be your choice for password storing: MD5 ,SHA1, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512? and would you be using salting?

Comment: @tugberk - Yes, salting is _essential_. And what I would use would depend on what I am trying to secure. Is it financial? Personal? Publicly available?

Comment: @tugberk - MD5 is not secure, SHA1 is not secure, read the posted article.  SHA512 is the most secure. You should always use a unique salt for each password.  If you use the same salt for every possible then its useless.  One even might say don't even store the entire hash, you don't need it, you only need enough to match the password.

Comment: @Oded for a publicly available website. BTW, what do you think about ASP.NET Membership provider's password management? is it secure enough? It uses a machine key to hash them I think, right?

Comment: @tugberk - "a publicly available website". But what user data are you trying to protect? Financial? Personal? Just the password? Can't give you an answer about the membership provider.

Comment: If I were to store a user's password.  I would generate a salt based on the account's creation time and username.  I might even add a magic number to that calculation.  This means you wouldn't have to store the salt itself, unless they got the source code, a malicious user would have no idea how to generate the salt.

Comment: @Oded hmm, not financial (I mean not certainly credit cards and any related credit card data). Mostly passwords for logins.

Comment: Hashing (well, cryptographic hashing, which is the subject of this question) IS cryptography. It is not encryption, which is another type of cryptography.

Comment: @Ramhound that's what ASP.NET Membership provider does I think.

Comment: @tugberk - You need to decide about the tradeoffs of the cost of hashing (can be processor intensive) and the cost of what you are protecting.

Comment: @tugberk - Yes the default membership is secure. You still need to store the password the correct way.  Lets put it this way.  Microsoft has 30 years in the computer industry.  I can guarantee you their method is more secure and has been tested by the community and thier own staff.

Comment: @tugberk - I have used the ASP.NET Membership role before.  It does not to my knowlege salt the password in that way.

Comment: "When generating hashes, always use a salt" - this should be "when hashing passwords, always use a salt". There are many uses for hashing algorithms other than password hashing.

Answer (score 3):

Hash functions are many to one functions. This means that many inputs will give the same result but that for any given input you get one and only one result.

Why this is so can be intuitively seen by considering a hash function that takes a string input of any length and generates a 32 bit integer. There are obviously far more strings than 2^32 which means that your hash function *cannot* give each input string a unique output. (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle for more discussion - the Uses and applications section specifically talks about hashes)

Given we now know that any result from our hash function could have been generated from one or more inputs and we have no information other than the result we have no way to determine which input was used so it cannot be reversed.

Comment: It might not be possible to be reversed, we can identify which pigeons go into what holes, which is the entire problem with MD5 there are not enough pigeon holes.

Comment: @Ramhound: I'm not clear on what you're talking about here. Are you just saying that the less pigeon holes there are the easier it is to find something that will go into a specific pigeon hole?

Comment: Yes that's what he is saying. Since MD5 has a somewhat short hash length of 128bits, there is only 2^128 different hashes any input can generate. So, you're going to have more collisions than something like SHA-512, which has a hash length of 512bits, resulting in 2^512 different possible hashes. The shorter length of MD5 is the primary reason it is considered to be insecure at this time.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two reasons:

1. Hashing usually uses asymmetric functions for calculations - meaning that finding reverse value of some operation is MUCH more difficult (in time/resources/efforts) than the direct operation.
2. Hashes of same algorithm are always of the same length  - meaning there is a limited set of possible hashes. This means that for every hash there will be **infinite** number of collisions - different source data block which form the same hash value.

Answer (score 1):

It's not encrypt/decrypt. For example, simple hash function:

```
int hash(int data)
{
    return data % 2;
}
```

Problem?

Comment: The poster is talking about cryptographic hashing, not "normal" hashing. Cryptographic hashes have properties that more straightforward/less-random hash functions do not -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

Answer (score 0):

Hashing is like using a checksum to verify data, not to encrypt or compress data.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially math, a Hash function is  a function that is NOT 1 to 1.   It takes a Range of inputs in the set of all binary data B* and maps it to  some fixed length binary string set Bn for fixed n or so.( this definition is onto however)
you can try and calculate the pre-image, of a given hash via brute force, but without knowing the size, it is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

You can hash any length of data you want, from a single byte to a terabyte file.  All possible data can be hashed to a 256 bit value (taking SHA-256 as an example).  That means that there are 2^256 possible values output from the SHA-256 hash algorithm.  However, there are a lot more than 2^256 possible values that can be input to SHA-256.  You can input any combination of bytes for any length you want.

Because there are far more possible inputs than possible outputs, then some of the inputs **must** generate the same output.  Since you don't know which of the many possible inputs generated the output, it is not possible to reliably go backwards.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple hash algorithm would be to take the first character of each word within a text. If you take the same text you can always get out the same hash but it is impossible to rebuilt the original text from only having the first character of each word.

Example hash from my answer above:

```
AvshawbtttfcoewwatIyttstycagotshbisitrtotfohtfcoew
```

And now try to find out the corresponding text from the given hash. ;-)

Comment: This doesn't address the author's question.

Comment: @Ramhound: The question was `I cannot understand why it is not possible to get the given text from the hash.` And i gave a simple to understand hash algorithm with an example where it is not possible to get out the original text from (my answer), but you can simply prove the correctness by taking the first character of each word in my answer.